# Filtering text in a file based from keywords in another file/dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to extract content of `.exe` files using `BinText`.

The result would contain list of strings and i would like to process it further by removing all windows API command (i.e: `GetProcess`) that i have defined in another configuration file, then output it to another file.

for example, if the file have strings such as :

- GetProcess
- 12345
- Hello World
- kernel32.dll
- LoadLibrary

It will remove `GetProcess`,`Kernel32.dll`, and `Load Library` if i have it defined in the config file.

Can you give me a hint on how to do this ? if there's an existing class that can help.

Comment: *Can you give me a hint on how to do this?*  Small hint- You have to write a program (Programmers all around the world recommend this)

Comment: yes i know i have to write the program, i am asking if there's an imported class that can help or have specific function to reach the aim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any specific class for doing this. I would do a simple script with just string ops to find wether I have to print or avoid printing a specific line.

I will assume you have the keywords you want to avoid in a text file, one in each line.

So my solution for this problem would be:

```
with open("config.txt") as cfile:
    words = cfile.readlines()
words = filter(None, words) # here we get rid of all empty lines, should there be any

with open("bintext-result.txt") as ifile:
    for line in ifile:
        if not(any([w in line for w in words])):
            print line.strip()
```

The logic is simple, at every line of the file, it checks if any of the words you don't want to see is present. If it found none, it prints the line. .strip() is used to avoid unnecesary spaces and the extra \n at the end of the line.

Comment: a very simple an elegant answer. I will try this route and will upvote this once i confirm the result! thanks again for the help !

Comment: Actually I realised I was a bit too sleepy and it does not work as it is now. Let me fix it.